# Get month week number from a date (2022-02-28T10:00:53.393Z) -> 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, momentjs

How to get week no from a date like `moment("2022-02-28T10:00:53.393Z")` should return 5.
I know about `week()` but that return week no from start of year like it will give `11` based on the date.
I need the week no. from month like week 1 of February or week 5 of February

Comment: momentjs has special methods for this: [`.week()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/) and [`.isoWeek()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: this one gives the week based on month not year

Comment: `moment("31/01/2022")` is undefined, unreliable behavior, as you can tell [from the warning you get for it](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/).

Comment: @SaGaR - *"this one gives the week based on month not year "* 1. That's not described in the question. 2. What does that even mean? Week in month instead of week in year? If so, it could be a reasonable question if you mean you also want (say) `1` for `2022-02-02`, but you'd have to be clear about it and call out why `week` isn't what you want, a well as defining how weeks are allocated (since it's complicated for week-in-year).

Comment: [If you add the format and use `weeks()` you'll get `6` as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/c28uyrz0/)

Comment: How do you define the first week of a month? As I said above, [it's complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) for week-of-year and different locales do it differently. From that link: Jan 1st 1977 is week 53 in the ISO week-of-year system.

Answer (score -5):

Here is the solution for this

```
const getWeekOfDate = (date) => {
  let startDate = moment(date).startOf('month').date();
  let endDate = moment(date).date();
  let weekCount = 1;
  for (let i = startDate; i <= endDate; i++) {
    if (
      moment(date).date(i).format('dddd') ===
      moment().startOf('week').format('dddd')
    ) {
      weekCount++;
    }
  }
  return weekCount;
};
```

Comment: Just use [`week`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/).

Comment: `week()` gives week based on year my function gives it based on month